# Array not displaying proper output

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing this program that calculates the amount of hours that employees work. If the employee ends up working more than 40 hours, than he'll get an additional time and half for every hour that passes 40. My issue is when it comes to the output. In the output, it shows the amount of sales tax, federal tax, gross income, and net; however if the employee puts in that he has worked less than 40 hours, everything displays properly; however, once the employee puts in that he has worked more than 40 hours for some reason it shows the taxes, and net, gross as 0.00.

For example, if less than 40, the following would display.

F-Name: L-Name: HorsWrked: HrlyRate: TimeHalf: S-Tax: F-Tax: Fica: Gross:

Employee Last    39.00      22.00    1.50    60.06   128.70  34.32   858.00

If more than 40, the following is being displayed.

F-Name: L-Name: HorsWrked: HrlyRate: TimeHalf: S-Tax: F-Tax: Fica: Gross:

Employee Last    45.00      22.00    1.50    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00

Any tips, hints, advice is appreciated.``

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()



{
//Set variables
int const size = 2;
double  timeHalf = 0.0, hoursWorked[size], gross[size], net[size], hourlyRate[size], totalTax;
string firstName[size], lastName[size];
const double stateTax = 0.07, fedTax = 0.15, fica = 0.04;
double sTax = 0.0, fTax = 0.0, fiTax;




for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)           //Initialize for loop
{

    cout<<"Please enter your first name? " <<endl;          //Display first name
    cin>>firstName[i];
    cout<<"Please enter your last name? " <<endl;           //Display last name
    cin>>lastName[i];
    cout<<"How many hours did you work? " <<endl;           //Dispaly hours worked
    cin>>hoursWorked[i];
    cout<<"What's the hourly rate? " <<endl;                //Display hourly rate
    cin>>hourlyRate[i];




  if(hoursWorked[i] < 40)
  {
      gross[i] = hoursWorked[i] * hourlyRate[i];

  }


  else if( hoursWorked[i] > 40)
  {
      gross[i] = hoursWorked[i] * (hourlyRate[i] * timeHalf);


  }
}

cout<<" \t\tXYX \n ";
cout<<"F-Name: L-Name: HorsWrked: HrlyRate: TimeHalf: S-Tax: F-Tax: Fica: Gross: Net: \n";

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{

    sTax = gross[i] * stateTax;
    fTax = gross[i] * fedTax;
    fiTax = gross[i] * fica;
    totalTax = gross[i] * (stateTax + fedTax + fica);
    timeHalf = 1.5;
    net[i] = gross[i] - totalTax;


    cout<<firstName[i]<<"\t " << setw(10) <<fixed <<setprecision(2) << lastName[i]<<"\t "
    << hoursWorked[i]<<"\t " <<hourlyRate[i] <<"\t " <<timeHalf<<"\t " <<sTax <<"\t "
    <<fTax <<"\t " <<fiTax <<"\t " <<gross[i] <<"\t " <<net[i] <<"\t ";
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you set a value to `timeHalf`, because it sure doesn't look like it. Also, you aren't handling if the hours worked ARE 40, only above or below

Comment: If an employee work more than 40 hours, are the first 40 hours then special or is it only the number of hours above 40 that require special treatment?

Comment: You get "an additional time and half for every hour that passes 40", but you're doing time and a half for all the hours.

Comment: @Tas I completely overlooked the timehalf, thought I set a value, but didn't. That ended up solving my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in your conditions, you check `if(hoursWorked[i] < 40)` and `if(hoursWorked[i] > 40)`, but there is no condition for `if(hoursWorked[i] == 40)`. You probably wanted to use -or-equal operator on one of these conditions (`>=` or `<=`).